# jQuery Dynamic Element click event not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dynamic page that gets loaded in. Inside that page there is a script that gets loaded in as well.

i.e. Page 1 loads Page 2. Page 2 looks like below -

```
<script src="someScript.js"></script>
<!-- HTML content below -->
<a class="myElement">with click event</a>
```

There are things in the script that run -

I run a bunch of `if` statements checking to make sure the right elements exists, and if not to add them.

```
//all of these statements fire and load in jquery as well as the missing elements
if (jQuery version is less than 1.7) load in jquery
if (certain elements dont exist) add elements
$('.myElement').each( add something to each myElement )

$(document).on('click', '.myElement', function() {
   //Click event never fires for myElement
});
```

What could be the reason that the click event is not firing?

Cannot be reproduced with a fiddle, but you can take a look here - https://www.metsales.com/MetropolitanSales/ConstantContact/MMF/Home.aspx

Complete script can be found - https://www.metsales.com/MetropolitanSales/Script/viewFrame.js

The issue involves the Data Sheet button

Comment: Move the script to the end of the body.

Comment: You can try attaching the event handler to the document only after the document is loaded. $(document).on('ready'). However, since your content is loaded dynamically (after page load) I am not 100% positive that is your issue. Could we have a look at the HTML and the load sequence?

Comment: Impossible to know with this code. Why don't you share the correct and real piece, reproducing the issue? With this code, event must be fired.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem** or error and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude impossible for me to reproduce the issue outside of my site. Feel free to take a look - https://www.metsales.com/MetropolitanSales/ConstantContact/MMF/Home.aspx? It's the Data Sheet button that this code is based around.

Comment: @Teemu if I move it to the end of the body, then I get an error saying `$(..).on() is undefined` but then checking the console I see jQuery 1.11 has been loaded.

Comment: In your page, the Data Sheet button have not the event attached, so the javascript is not reached at this point. Where is the javascript that needs to be executed? I don't know, you don't tell me :)

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude its the `viewFrame.js` file in the resources. Didn't want to post a wall of code, so the pseudo code captures the structure well, but not the code. https://www.metsales.com/MetropolitanSales/Script/viewFrame.js

Comment: `viewFrame.js` is not included in the page, so its code will never executed. Include it with the correct `<script>` tag and should work. I can see it because in the debugger there are lots of javascript files but `viewFrame.js` doesn't exists.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude right - I see that as well, but then why are some of the functions executing?

Comment: The problem is with your jquery version. I am seeing `$(...).on is not a function'. on function is not available before 1.9

Comment: @user2181397 I don't see that error. My console is clean of errors, only show console.log() strings.

Comment: @Adjit no idea for that. Maybe that file is compiled in another file? If you don't know this, me less.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude not sure if this helps, but you can look in the console, and the line that says `success Loading jQuery - VM26139:21` you can click on that and see the file, but it doesn't appear in the resources... I feel like this should work, and I actually had a page with this working last week... I just checked on it and it is no longer working

Comment: Clicking in that (success Loading jquery) goes to a page `view-source:https://www.metsales.com/MetropolitanSales/Script/jQuery/jqueryLoader.min.js` that doesn't exists. Its content is a 404 error. So I don't know why it says "success" when obviously is an error.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude figured it out... so I changed my usage of `<script src="viewFrame.js">` to using `$.getScript` and wrapping that in `$(document).ready()` in file 2

Comment: I can't see it. Sorry but I think this error is a mistery for me. I don't see the correct inclusion of viewFrame.js in the whole page, I can't see the definitions of the functions, I can see a console.log that throws me to a 404 file.... Really I don't know what more can I do to know what happens

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude thats ok. Thanks for the help though! If you take a look now the script should be working properly, it just "doesn't exist" lol

Comment: Yeah, the strange thing that I can see the console.log produced, but not the file that throws that console.log. Something very weird. If you know what can we do to reach that piece of code, please, tell us as soon as possible.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude could it be that the file is only available to me since I am on the network?

Comment: I'm not sure. I see that you are on HTTPS, so maybe something goes from here. I've revised all includes and all are retrieved by https, so there's no reason to be a problem, but maybe... who knows?